# Angular, how to check map keys

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have the problem with below map, I know, that there is a object (key value), but when I checked it in if loop:

> if (!!state.get(namePersons).has(workData)) { console.log('true'); }

I got error about:

> cannot read property has

Map is:

```
 Map<namePersons, Map<workData, InformationModel>>>
```

Comment: Map is always problematic in type script...

Comment: can you make sure the double `!` at the beginning of your condition is not a typo ? Right now, you are checking that the return value of  `.has(workData)` exists, which is redundent.

Comment: Checked everything. Without ```!!```, also ```if (!!state.get(namePersons) &&state.get(namePersons).has(workData))``` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of **`namePersons`** is not exitsed in Map then `get()` will return undefined that's the reason you are getting the error..

Try this :

```
if (!!state.get(namePersons) && !!state.get(namePersons).has(workData)) { 
     console.log('true'); 
}
```

(may be you need check the condition as per requirement), refer here for more info about [**`Map in Typescript`**](https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-map)